# Can Genasi derive from stock other than human?

Tags: dnd-5e, races, racial-traits

Inspired by this question: [Can Tieflings derive from stock other than human?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/114470/35259)

Crudely speaking, tieflings are half-human, half-devil. However, as the answer to the other question points out, non-human half-devils/demons exist, such as the Fey'ri, who are half-elven, half-demon.

Genasi are half-human, half-genie (again, crudely speaking). **Are there any non-human half-genie races**, such as a half-elven, half-genie race or a half-dwarven, half-genie race?

I'm not that interested in a specific setting, but if setting matters, let's go with the Forgotten Realms (or at the very least, not Eberron/Ravnica).

Comment: Is this just for flavor or are you looking for mechanical effects of a different race?

Comment: @NautArch Primarily flavour, although if there were any mechanical differences somehow then that would be interesting to know about too.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Genasi can be from another race than human. You can see the description of genasi from the [*Elemental Evil Player's Companion*](http://dnd.wizards.com/sites/default/files/media/EE-Players-Companion_0_0.pdf), **pg. 7** (under ["Heirs to Elemental Power"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/races/genasi#HeirstoElementalPower)):

> A given genasi might have some features reminiscent of the mortal parent (pointed ears from an elf, a stockier frame and thick hair from a dwarf, small hands and feet from a halfling, exceedingly large eyes from a gnome, and so on).

Comment: Including Tiefling-Genasi?

Comment: @Cœur I doubt that would be intended. Historically, you can only be "touched" by one plane. Elemental planes used to be separate before 4E wherein they were merged into the Primordial goo, but it is still a plane with 4 variance in how races can be touched. It would be like trying to have an Aasimar Tiefling in my mind.

Answer (score 4):

I have found a couple of named races in my own investigations from previous editions, but nothing from 5e.

As far as I know these races have not been included in anything 5e-related, and the only official source for these races seem to come from a [Dragon magazine](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Dragon_magazine_350) for 3e, which I don't have, hence this information is only what I can find online from Wikipedia or Forgotten Realms Wiki.

But for what it's worth, here's what I found (maybe someone with that magazine could edit this/submit their own answer with better information; it's still not 5e related, but it's something that someone could homebrew, at least).

### D'hin'ni

The d'hin ([1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27hin%27ni), [2](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/D%27hin%27ni)) are a race of half-lightfoot halflings and half-[djinni](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/djinni) (air elemental genies).

> A d'hin'ni was a type of planetouched that was the combination of a **genie ancestor** and **halfling** (or hin as they were also called) blood.
>
> Commonly descended from slave **lightfoot hin** and their **djinn** masters, they mixed the halfling's disinterest in the battles of morals and ethics, but the unpredictibility of djinn caused the majority of them to take the chaotic neutral alignment. *(from [Forgotten Realms Wiki](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/D%27hin%27ni))*

### Azerblood

The azerblood ([1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Dungeons_%26_Dragons_creatures_(A)#Azerblood)) are a race of half-mountain dwarves and half-[azer](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/azer) (fire elementals, though not genies).

> An azerblood is a type of planetouched that is the combination of a fire outsider known as an **azer** and **dwarven** blood [...]
>
> Azerblood resemble a dwarf of the **shield dwarf subrace** for the most part, with some variations based on the outsider blood that flows in their veins[citation needed]. Common traits are metallic brass-coloured skin, flame-red hair and irises that appear to move with flames. *(from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Dungeons_%26_Dragons_creatures_(A)#Azerblood))*

Comment: Whereas helpful for precedent these are half-bloods which are not the same as planetouched. I honestly really miss templates. Genasi and Tiefling and Aasimar really should have been made into templates to avoid this sort of confusion.